# Check if the time is past 9pm using PHP

Tags: php, datetime, date

What I am trying to do is I have a selected date formatted as below:

```
$selectedDate = 2010/02/24
```

I want to check it is both todays date and it is past 9pm on the server and set a value if it is.

I can get a time by using the following:

```
$checkTime = date("H:i");
```

I want to create something like:

```
if ($checkTime > 21:00 && $selectedDate == date("Y/m/d")) { //do my stuff }
```

But a bit unsure of the syntex.

Many thanks for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$checkDate = '2010-02-24';
$checkTime = '2100';

if( date( 'Y-m-d' ) == $checkDate && date( 'Hi' ) >= $checkTime ) {
    // Do something clever
}
```

Note the use of `Hi` as the date format string, which allows for a numerical comparison.

Comment: Took me a while to figure out why you stuck the dummy string "Hi" in there. Then I felt smart.

Comment: Awesome, however one slight problem. It all works when I use a "hard coded date" which is when a user selects a date, however if I use:
    date("Y/m/d")
which is the default if no date is selected then the match doesn't work. Do I need to do anything to this?

Comment: Don't worry, completly missed the -, I was using / to split the D M Y! many thanks for your help

Comment: Why use Hi and not just H and compare against 21? You don't include seconds, so why minutes?

Comment: More or less arbitrary. I could have worked out 21.00 in Swatch beats and used that as the comparison.